# Bare Metal in gem5 for RISC-V

Tags: riscv, bare-metal, gem5

I want to know if there is a way to test bare-metal (without OS) in gem5 for RISC-V processor. Neither se nor fs mode has an option about it. I have compiled a C programm with elf gcc compiler but se mode assume Linux OS. Any Ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: My understanding is that full system mode lets you supply your own kernel (insert your program instead of the kernel) that is then run (bare metal) on the simulated hardware. Do you have some other understanding of the mode or some other expectation for bare-metal running?

Comment: Other options that are not gem5: spike, qemu